# Minimal linux live persistence

Tags: live-usb, persistence

I am new to Linux. I was trying Minimal Linux Live recently. Is there a way by which I can ensure persistence in the Linux? Example, if I create a file it must stay there even after rebooting.

Comment: Then don't use a live system. Simple.

Comment: Do you mean in a USB?

Comment: @guillermo chamorro I want to use minimal linux but dont want to use it in live mode..Also in minimal linux live they have compiled linux from scratch..If i am able to do that but with some persistence then it would be good for me

Comment: What's wrong with installing the system to the harddrive? Do you just want a persistent partition? Edit your question to include what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I strongly doubt that you can get persistence to work on that distro, or at least it would be a very complicated process.

Comment: Okay..Thanks for your replies

Answer (score 1):

Persistence **does work** in Minimal Linux Live and it is supported in two different forms. Look at the [QEMU test script header](https://github.com/ivandavidov/minimal/blob/master/src/qemu-bios.sh#L3), where you can find how to try/test this feature.

Note that the persistence support is not a feature that comes just like that, out of the box. You have to explicitly rebuild MLL and activate the [folder overlay](https://github.com/ivandavidov/minimal/blob/master/src/.config#L96) option, or the [sparse overlay](https://github.com/ivandavidov/minimal/blob/master/src/.config#L89) option. Depending on what option you choose, your changes will be persisted in a special folder (thus the *folder overlay* naming), or in special image file (sparse file, to be precise, thus the *sparse overlay* naming). Also, depending on your choice, you have to ensure that the boot media contains either a `/minimal` folder (for folder overlay) or the special image file `/minimal.img`. Also, since there is no official installer for MLL, you'll have to use the [Syslinux](https://www.syslinux.org) utilities (e.g. [extlinux](https://wiki.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=EXTLINUX)) in order to prepare your boot loader. And you'll also have to use [fdisk](https://linux.die.net/man/8/fdisk) or any other disk management tool in order to prepare the disk partition(s).

I suggest you try the `folder overlay` and use one big EXT2 filesystem for your USB flash device. Then you copy/extract the ISO structure in the root USB flash device folder and execute `extlinux` with proper arguments, in order to make the USB flash device bootable. In fact, this can be described as a series of simple steps to follow in the main MLL "readme" document.

Comment: It's interesting that the author of Minimal Linux Live gets downvoted when he provides a helpful reply to a question about Minimal Linux Live.